# Is this the transformer for my door chime?

Tags: electrical, uk, doorbell

I'm looking to install Ring Pro doorbell. I have looked around the junction box for a transformer and couldn't seem to find one this is the inside of the chime.

[image: Inside of doorbell chime]

If this isn't it where could it be ?

Comment: No,  that looks like the door bell mechanism itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - that is not the transformer.
The transformer could be located in the furnace closet, the garage, laundry room.

If you are installing the Ring doorbell, you do not need to locate the transformer.  You should be able to connect to the existing two wires where the old doorbell pushbutton was located.  Attach the two wires to the back of the Ring doorbell.   From your picture, your original doorbell was AC power, so that is good.

Answer (score 2):

The transformer could be anywhere - ours is under the stairs, and looks like this: 
[image]
The thing you have shown is the solenoid block which actually rings the bell.

You can see two wires going out of the bottom. One is going to your doorbell, the other is going to the transformer.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a box behind the chime base look to see if you can tell which way the wires go. Most of the ones I have installed are in the attic above the chime, if your furnace / electrical closet is close to the front door it may be in there [photo](https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/664f45cf-e585-4150-a584-c8193a4a5885/svn/newhouse-hardware-doorbell-transformers-30tr-64_1000.jpg) many times attached to an electrical box but most look like this. You can only see the low voltage side and the wires that feed the chime go to the screws. I should say the ones I have installed or seen in the US.